# Solution of the Laplacian equation with constant gradient on a given ball?

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

Let $u\in H^1(\Omega)$ be the weak solution of the Laplacian equation in the unit cube $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$, $n \leq 3$, with inhomogeneous Neumann conditions on $\Gamma_N$ and homogeneous Dirichlet conditions on $\Gamma_D$. That is, $u$ solves
$$- \Delta u = 0 \ \text{ in } \Omega,
\qquad \frac{\partial u}{\partial n}= g \ \text{ on } \Gamma_N,
 \qquad u = 0 \ \text{ on } \Gamma_D.$$

Fix an arbitrary open ball $B \subset \Omega$. Given $c \in \mathbb{R}^n$, is it possible to choose Neumann data $g$ (in a suitable space) such that
$$\nabla u = c \quad \text{ a.e. on } B?$$

If this is not the case, then how can I characterize attainable gradient fields?

Idea: Green's function might be a suitable tool to address this question.

Comment: 1) Since you mention Neumann data, do you mean to take $\frac{\partial u}{\partial n} = g$ on $\Gamma_N$? 2) If $\nabla u = c$, then $\nabla (u(x) - c \cdot x) = 0$, which means that $u(x) = c \cdot x + b$ on the ball $B$. By unique continuation, this holds on the whole of $\Omega$. 3) What kind of characterization would satisfy you?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Add 1) Sure, that's right. Add 2) Can you please explain this continuation argument in detail? Add 3) Ideally, I would like to have a characterization of the gradient via the boundary loads.

Comment: It's a well-known fact that harmonic functions are real-analytic, and thus their value on any open set determines their value globally. Since the global function $x \mapsto c \cdot x+b$ is harmonic and equal to $u$ on the open ball, it must be equal to $u$ everywhere. Now that you know $u$ must be linear, you should easily be able to work out the ramifications for the boundary data.